# How can I enable fingerprint on my HP elitebook

Tags: 22.04, hp, syslinux

I can't find the option to enable fingerprint lock on my PC, HP EliteBook 820 G3, I am running ubuntu 22.04.

here is the output of my lsusb

```
ubuntu@mypc:~$ lsusb    
    Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
    Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05c8:0383 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) HP HD Camera
    Bus 001 Device 003: ID 138a:003f Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS495 Fingerprint Reader
    Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
    Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: There is currently [no support](https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:138a-003f) for that particular fingerprint reader. You *might* have some luck with [a custom libfprint driver](https://github.com/rindeal/libfprint-vfs_proprietary-driver), but it has not been updated for 22.04 

Comment: @matigo Thanks you, maybe I have to wait till it becomes available

Comment: Hi, some times was passing, was 'the driver' meanwhile developed? :) Thank you