Fingerprint reader is not working
I want to install my fingerprint reader on my laptop (HP Elitebook 820 G1), but I can't. I have this small  scanner on the laptop, but when typing lsusb and don't see a fingerprint scanner:
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. Integrated Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0424:5534 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 05c8:0374 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) HP EliteBook integrated HD Webcam
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 03f0:581d HP, Inc lt4112 Gobi 4G Module Network Device
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0424:2134 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1423991/how-can-i-enable-fingerprint-on-my-hp-elitebook

first you need to check if your fingerprint reader is on here, to check it run lsusb, don't worry if it's not. The list of supported devices is not updated regularly and is not complete. It is worth testing your device using the instructions on this page even if it does not appear on that list, then install fprintd, imagemagick might also be needed. Add pam_fprintd.so as sufficient to the top of the auth section of /etc/pam.d/system-local-login
auth      sufficient pam_fprintd.so
auth      include   system-login

This tries to use fingerprint login first, and if it fails or if it finds no fingerprint signatures in the given user's home directory, it proceeds to password login. You will need to have an authentication agent/polkit running before being able to enroll your finger print. To add a signature for a finger, run:     fprintd-enroll
To verify the newly created fingerprint, use:
fprintd-verify
By default every user is allowed to enroll new fingerprints without prompting for the password or the fingerprint. You can change this behavior using polkit rules.
There are two locations that contains the polkit configuration files
/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/
/usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d/

You should not modify the files under /usr/share/polkit-1/rules.d/ because they will be overwritten on update. Copy them to /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/ first.
In the following example only root can enroll fingerprints
/etc/polkit-1/rules.d/50-net.reactivated.fprint.device.enroll.rules

polkit.addRule(function (action, subject) {
  if (action.id == "net.reactivated.fprint.device.enroll") {
    return subject.user == "root" ? polkit.Result.YES : polkit.Result.NO
  }
})

source
